# Point anomalies vs collective anomalies in time series

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

The [Anomaly Detection survey](http://cucis.ece.northwestern.edu/projects/DMS/publications/AnomalyDetection.pdf) by Chandola et al categorizes anomalies into point anomalies and collective anomalies. Do we need this type of categorization in anomaly detection in time series, though? Can't I always map time series data point of a time range into a single data point (e.g., a representative vector), and then apply a point-anomaly detector? Do we know if there's any effective anomaly detection algorithm that can't be equivalent to the aforementioned method, namely applying a point-anomaly detector to representation (as a single data point) of individual range of a time series?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Collective anomalies are not limited to sections of time. They can occur also when you are measuring the attribute on many sensors. A value can then be OK when seen in isolation (single datastream), but a collective anomaly when affecting many sensors.

I tried to explain it in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/406626/201327).

Comment: Thanks, @jonnor. In this case, can we simply treat multiple streams as a multi-variate time series, find a representation accordingly, and then feed the representation as data points to a point-anomaly detector?

Comment: Yes that is fine